# 3D Touch View Controller For Location not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uikit, 3dtouch

I implemented 3D touch in my app, by registering my view controller with my table view as a source rect. And it's been working fine for the past couple weeks since I implemented it.

But I just tried it out and found that it no longer seems to be working. I didn't touch any of that code, so I don't know what the problem is.

The view controller is definitely being registered for `UIViewControllerPreviewing` but `previewingContext(previewingContext: viewControllerForLocation:)` isn't even being called!

I don't know what else there is to do to set this up apart from register for previewing, and nothing I do seems to trigger that method. I have a separate view controller where 3D touch seems to be working fine, but I'm not doing anything differently.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why the method isn't even being called? This is really frustrating me since it just seems to have stopped working because it was working fine earlier. Thanks.

Here is the code for my `previewingContext(previewingContext: viewControllerForLocation:)` method:

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = "ClipPlayerViewController"

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location), let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as? ClipPlayerViewController else { return nil }

    let effect = filteredEffectsSortedBySection[indexPath.section].effects[indexPath.row]

    switch effect.mediaType {
    case .Video:
        destination.effect = effect

        destination.showsPlaybackControls = false

        if let thumbnail = thumbnailsForEffects[effect], let unwrappedThumbnail = thumbnail {
            destination.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(unwrappedThumbnail.size.width - 2, unwrappedThumbnail.size.height - 2)
        } else if let effectSize = destination.player?.currentItem?.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first?.naturalSize {
            destination.preferredContentSize = effectSize
        }

        previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.frame

        return destination

    case .Texture:
        return nytPhotosViewControllerForEffectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}
```

And here is the code where I register for previewing, called in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
if  traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {        
    registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: tableView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade to Swift3? If yes, check if the delegate function params are matching.

Also, remember to check that registerForPreviewing is called properly.

```
   registerForPreviewing(with: self as! UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, sourceView: view)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't updated to Swift 3 on that project yet (and still haven't figured out what the problem with this is)

Comment: ah right. If you share your viewControllerForLocation delegate function I can check it with my version that works.

Comment: Cool! Is the  registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view) triggering for sure? And, if you put a breakpoint, is the first line of viewControllerForLocation being hit?

Comment: Yes, registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView) is getting called. viewControllerForLocation is not.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Swift 3 migrator. (Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax)

You seem to be already using the Swift 3 compiler — if you were still on Swift 2, method calls you say are working (like `registerForPreviewing(with:sourceView:)` and `tableView.cellForRow(at:)`) would fail to compile, because those are the Swift 3 syntax for those APIs.

If the migrator fails to catch it, the Swift 3 method signature for your delegate method is `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)` — note the underscore indicating that there's no argument label on the first parameter, so your declaration should look like:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, 
    viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
```

Comment: You're right. That was from an old version where I tried to update to Swift 3 but I had some issues with some of the CocoaPods I was using. The version of the project that actually builds is in Swift 2.3. I updated my original post to show the code it's actually currently using (in Swift 2.3 -- migrating still gives me issues with pods)